# Laravel Dusk Visit method keeps going back to APP_URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have the following on my `TimelineTest` Dusk file

```
$browser->visit('/wall/' . $this->username . '/' . $this->userID)
                    ->assertTitleContains($this->username . ' - SiteName');
```

But although I am specifying the url to visit, my test fails because Dusk still visits the root `/` and not the url I specified `/wall/' . $this->username . '/' . $this->userID`

I dumped the current url using

```
$url = $browser->driver->getCurrentURL();
dd($url);
```

And it is the correct one, but my assertion fails saying that my title was not found in the page title, which corresponds to the one in the index page `/`

Did anyone have Dusk not visiting the URL they specified?

Comment: What does the screenshot show?

Comment: It shows my 500 error screen, nothing on the logs though...

Comment: Is it a generic 500 page or does it contain an exception stacktrace? Do you have debugging enabled?

Comment: @Alucard show us a screenshot and the result of the output from the command line when you run the dusk.

Comment: Try to see it in browser with headless mode commented out. Also, Is there a possibility of redirection from your desired page to home page ?